# Binding extension required in app.config

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I am using Service Bus in my project. I am referring Version 2.0.0.0 dll.

When I add following tag in my app.config everything works fine

```
     <extensions>
        <bindingExtensions>
           <add name="netTcpRelayBinding"      
           type =
           "Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.NetTcpRelayBindingCollectionElement, 
            Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
            PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        </bindingExtensions>
     </extensions>
```

but as soon as I remove this tag, it gives following error

***Configuration binding extension 'system.serviceModel/bindings/netTcpRelayBinding' could not be found. 
Verify that this binding extension is properly registered in system.serviceModel/extensions/bindingExtensions and that it is spelled correctly.***

Is it mandatory to provide this tag because on some other machine it is working fine without this tag.

Answer (score 1):

This is required for WCF to be able to load this binding from the correct dll. There are cases where you can add this to other config files like machine.config and WCF will pick it from there and hence the app will work without having it in the app.config file.

Comment: But problem is that it works on machine which have single version of Azure SDK and it gives error when multiple versions of Azure SDk, in that case we have to remove BindingExtensions tag from the config then it works fine